# Is playing Dr. Mundo solo top a viable pick?

Tags: league-of-legends

I just need to know if I should play mundo in the jungle or in top. I feel like top lane, he stomps on some champions, but in the jungle he's almost always around for counterjungling.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, his jungle is much too strong to be wasted in top lane.

Dr. Mundo has incredibly fast camp clears (W AOE damage), buff/dragon control (Q's % damage), 1v1 potential (Exhaust + E + Q chasing), escape (W's cc reduction, R's trademark healing and movespeed buff).

Comment: What sorts of runes do you recommend for jungle mundo?

Comment: Attack Speed Reds.  Armor Yellows.  Flat or Scaling Magic Resist Blues (preference/enemy team comp).  Movement Speed Purples.  This is the setup I run.  The Attack Speed scales well with Mundo with his E Attack Damage buff.  Armor Pen isn't necessary because a large part of Mundo's camp clearing is through his W (AOE magic damage).

Comment: So 
AS Reds
Armour Seals
MR/lvl blues?

Comment: Sorry, the editing is weird for comments.  It should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer mundo toplane. I save the jungle for a bursty or strong cc jungler. In the toplane he can farm and get the very important gold he requires for all his tank items. As a jungler, if you dont get solid ganks/ assists, then you are gonna lack on gold, or end up farming in the jungle and not being able to provide needed lane pressure for your team. His early game he can't go Rambo like he can lategame, so keep that in mind.. I start reju bead ward and 5 reds, and farming/harassing is solid with his Q ( as long as u dont miss). I build sunfire cape or spirit visage depending on who I am facing in lane, ap or ad wise. I try to hold the lane towards my tower , just like I do with Shen, so that my jungler can have room for good gank opportunities. If you have a good harass in your lane , then you can position yourself between the minions and the opponent In order to deny farm.